# return value and end function

Tags: r, return

I want to return value from the function and end the function on the line where value is returned.

```
myfunc <- function(){   
    if(TRUE){
        return(1) #end function here and do not execute the rest of the code.
    }
    if(FALSE){
        return(2)
    }
   return(3)
}
```

but when execute this function it returns `3`. how can I return only value if the first condition is true?

Comment: `when execute this function it returns 3`. Not exactly. If I run your function as myfunc() it returns 1. What is that you are looking for? A concrete example would have been helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
myfunc <- function(condition){   
    if(condition) return(1)
    else return(2)
} 

myfunc <- function(condition){   
    if(condition) return(1)
    2 # the last call in a function is returned
} 

myfunc()

[1] 1
```

Comment: what if 2 conditions are not true and I want to return a default value in the end of the function?

Comment: You need an `else` condition for that. Let me change that in the answer

Comment: I know I can do it with if-else blocks but it's not an efficient solution. if first condition true then it won't check each IF is true or not.

Comment: Yes, if the first condition is `TRUE` then you stop the function by returning a value and the rest of the code is not evaluated. That's what your question was about, or not?